# Vue.js - how can i splice data start from back?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to splice data start from back. (Start splicing with a higher index)

when .delete (div) click, .image-box(div) have to delete start from back.

how can i do?

```js
<div class = "image-cover">
    <div class = "image-box"  v-for = "(image, index) in images" :key = "image.id" >
        <div class = "index">{{ index }}</div>
        <img :src = "image.url" class = "previewImage"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "delete" @click="deleteImage" v-on:click  = "delete image in here!">-</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want to remove the last elements (highest index) first?

If so, just use `images.length` to get the last index:

```
images.splice(images.length - 1, 1); // splice off the last image
```

If you need to splice multiple, just subtract `(1 + numberToRemove)` from `images.length`:

```
images.splice(images.length - 4, 3); // splice off the last 3
```

or:

```
const numToRemove = 3;
images.splice(images.length - 1 - numToRemove, numToRemove);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you are perfect!